# C# executing specific code

Tags: c#, command-line-interface

I was wondering if there's a possibility to execute a specific piece of code by the user when running the program (The program is command line interface).

The program executes everything in order but that's not what I want.

Here are two screenshots of how the program runs and the code behind it.

[[image: Program while running]]

```
        // Read all the bookings between dates:
        Console.WriteLine("Input start date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
        DateTime bookingStartDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Input end date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
        DateTime bookingEndDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        DbBookings bookings = new DbBookings(bookingStartDate, bookingEndDate);
        foreach (DbBooking booking in bookings.Bookings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("booking start date = " + booking.startDate);
            Console.WriteLine("booking end date = " + booking.endDate);
            Console.WriteLine("booking room No = " + booking.roomNo);
            Console.WriteLine("booking guest = " + booking.guestName);
            Console.WriteLine("booking guest phone No = " + booking.guestPhone);
            Console.WriteLine("booking cost = " + booking.cost);
        }


        //Create a new booking
        Console.WriteLine("Bed and breakfast create new booking");

        Console.WriteLine("Input start date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Input end date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("What room?");
        int room = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Customer Name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Customer phone number");
        string phone = Console.ReadLine();
        double cost = (endDate.ToOADate() - startDate.ToOADate()) * 29;

        DbBooking newBooking = new DbBooking(
            startDate,
            startDate,
            room,
            name,
            phone,
            cost
            );
        Console.ReadLine();
```

What I want the program to do is to ask 2 questions, 'Do you want to read the bookings' and 'Do you want to add new booking' you would answer these to questions by typing '1' or '2'

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141262/5174469) should give you the right start of how to create such an interface

Comment: Test arguments count.  If zero the get inputs from ReadLine().  If greater than zero get values from args array.  Use :  args.Count()

Comment: Do not post pictures of your code, copy the code in to the question then highlight it and press the toolbar button that looks like `{ }` if the code does not look properly formatted in the preview window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce logic into your code if you want it to behave differently based on different user input values. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) will explain how the `if`, `else if`, and `else` keywords work. Also, if you want to expand your knowledge of branching further you could use [`switch` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to read the bookings?");
    string response = Console.ReadLine();
    if (response == "1")
        ReadBookings();
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to create a booking?");
        response = Console.ReadLine();
        if (response == "1")
            CreateBooking();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ReadBookings() {
    DateTime startDate, endDate;

    Console.WriteLine("Input start date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
    startDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Input end date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
    endDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    DbBookings bookings = new DbBookings(bookingStartDate, bookingEndDate);
    foreach (DbBooking booking in bookings.Bookings)
        Console.WriteLine($"booking start date: {booking.startDate}\nbooking end date: {booking.endDate}\nbooking room No: {booking.roomNo}\nbooking guest: {booking.guestName}\nbooking guest phone No: {booking.guestPhone}\nbooking cost: {booking.cost});
}

static void CreateBooking() {
    DateTime startDate, endDate;
    string name, phone;
    int room;
    double cost;

    Console.WriteLine("Bed and breakfast create new booking");
    Console.WriteLine("Input start date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
    startDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Input end date in the format yyyy-mm-dd");
    endDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("What room?");
    room = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Customer Name");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Customer phone number");
    phone = Console.ReadLine();
    cost = (endDate.ToOADate() - startDate.ToOADate()) * 29;

    DbBooking newBooking = new DbBooking(startDate, endDate, room, name, phone, cost);
}
```

Comment: Also note that Console.WriteLine handles replacements just like string.Format, and C# 6.0 has the '$' character that behaves the same but in a more readable fashion. You can use it just like the '@' verbatim.